# Why is the electrical angle = p/2 times the mechanical angle for a DC machine?

Tags: dc-motor

Can anybody tell me why the electrical angle = p/2 times the mechanical angle in a DC machine.

Here p is the number of poles.

In specific I want explanation for the solution give here:

[image]

There is some analogy that EMF induced (l* **v** x **B**) in conductors under the north pole and in conductors under south pole will be out of phase (if we look at it from the top of the armature not along the loop of the coil.) This way total 360 physical angle is equal to 180 pole pairs. Now they are generalizing for any angle. How is this possible?

Any detailed answer is highly appreciated.

Comment: Because one electrical cycle rotates the rotor by one N pole and one S pole. In a 6 pole motor for example, you have to do that 3 times for one full mechanical revolution.

Comment: Yes, I agree that emf induced in conductors under N pole and S pole is 180 degree. But how can we generalise this? That is my doubt

Comment: Then it is difficult to know what you are really asking. Especially since 360 degrees electrical angle equals 1 pole pair, not 180. And I can't see any generalising in the quoted picture : it is only an explanation of what they call a short winding. On the face of it, that would be less efficient, but there must be some advantage (or perhaps some mechanical necessity like slot 7 being taken by another winding. You'll just have to read the rest of the text to find out.